# how to take the root of a very large number?

Tags: c++

```
given x=4 and y=1296;
we need to solve for z in z^x=y; 
we can calculate z=6 in various ways;
```

Question is how do I find z if y is a very large number greater than 10^100? I obviously can't store that number as int, so how would I go about calculating z?

C++ implementation would be nice, if not, any solution will work.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/

Comment: You are perhaps looking for a "bignum" or "arbitrary precision arithmetic" library, such as [GNU MP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: You might also want to ask on mathematics.stackexchange.com for alternative algorithms.

Comment: welcome to the land of logs: hint log(z^x) = x*log(z)

Comment: What are you guys on about? show the implementation or don't bother pretending to sound smart...

Comment: @WhozCraig `(z^x)^(1/x)=y^(1/x)` <=> `z=y^(1/x)` No logs needed. Logs are needed if z and y are known, but x is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the accuracy required. Since 1e100 cannot be exactly represented by a double, you have a problem.

This works, if you are willing to accept that it does not yield an exact solution. But then, I just said that 1e100 is not represented exactly as a double anyway. Thus, in MATLAB,

```
exp(log(1e100)/4)
ans =
                     1e+25
```

Ok, so it looks like 1e25 is the answer, but is it really? In fact, the number we really get, in terms of a double, is: 10000000000000026675773440.

One problem is the original number was not represented exactly anyway. So 1e100, when stored in the IEEE format, is more accurately stored as something like this:

```
1.00000000000000001590289110975991804683608085639452813897813e100
```

To solve this exactly, you would best be served by a big integer form, but a big decimal form would do reasonably well too.

Thus, in MATLAB, using my big decimal (HPF) form we see that 1e100 is exactly represented in 100 digits of precision.

```
x = hpf('1e100',100)
x =
1.e100
```

And, to 100 digits of precision, the root is correct.

```
exp(log(x)/4)
ans =
10000000000000000000000000
```

Actually though, be careful, as any floating point form cannot represent real numbers exactly. To more precision, we see that the number computed was actually slightly in error:

9999999999999999999999999.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999800

A big integer form will yield an exact result, if one exists. Thus, using a big integer form, we see the expected result:

```
vpi(10)^100
ans =
    10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000                                       

nthroot(vpi(10)^100,4)
ans =
    10000000000000000000000000
```

The point is, to do the computation you desire, you need to use tools that can do the computation. There are many such big decimal or big integer tools to be had. For example, Java has a [BigDecimal and a BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/package-summary.html) form that I have used on occasion (though I've written my own tools anyway, thus in MATLAB, [HPF](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class) and [VPI](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic).)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do something evil with logarithms

maybe there is a library that you can find that lets you deal with  big integers

Comment: Its not evil, Evil... that somehow sounds redundant. =P. And I think you're spot-on unless he's going for modulo chaining, and since I do't see any mods in the problem.. Evil = +1.

Comment: As per my comment on the OP, logarithms won't help here. Logs are needed if z is known, but exponents if x is known. Consider `x^2 = 4`. We can take the 1/2 power of both sides (i.e. sqrt): `x^(2*1/2) = 4^(1/2)`, giving us `x=2`. Moreover, for x,y,z `x^z=y <=> x=y^(1/z)`

Comment: Question is not how to solve for z, but rather what happens when the input y is too large that you can't store it in say unsigned long long to even perform arithmetic operations on...

Comment: I think you are reading the question differently that me Sadf.  If 10^ 100 won't fit in your available representation you can use a log based representation which may make it fit.  X * LOG10(Z) = LOG10(Y) yields LOG10(Z) = LOG10(Y) / X, where X != 0.   It looks quite straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). In this case you need to use [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

I.e. you need to write class for arbitrary-precision number. It would be composition of mantissa, which is represented by array of digits and exponent, which is represented by integer. You should realize basic operations on numbers similar to pencil-and-paper methods. Then you should realize Newton's algoriithm as described in wiki.